# Spring batch Using reader with partitioner

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have job that reads files and writes them into DB. For better performance I want to split my step so I will read few files at once so I use partitioner. Here relevant configuration

```
Step partitionedStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
        .partitioner(buildSingleFileStep(entityManagerFactory, stepBuilder))
        .partitioner("flatfileToDbStep", buildPartitioner())
        .taskExecutor(stepTaskExecutor)
        .build();
```

buildSingleFileStep:

```
    private TaskletStep buildSingleFileStep(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, SimpleStepBuilder stepBuilder) {
        return stepBuilder
                .reader(readerFactory.getReader())
                .writer(new SomeWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

I'm using standard MultiResourcePartitioner and MultiResourceItemReader

During job execution I'm getting error java.io.IOException: Stream closed
After googeling, I've found that reader is statefull and cannot be used in multithread environment. My question is how can I configure my reader?

PS. I've tried @StepScope annotion but without success.

Thanks

Comment: Using step scope is the correct way...can you provide the configuration you tried and what happened?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. I've managed to late bind fileName to reader using @ StepScope and @ Value annotation on parameter